# Very slow simple mysql query

Tags: mysql, database-partitioning

I have a very slow mysql query as follows:

```
SELECT function,  CONVERT_TZ(`time`, '+01:00','+01:00') 
FROM `function_logger` 
WHERE unit_id=3067785 
  and part_id=3 and channel=0  
  and `time` > NOW()-INTERVAL 1 DAY 
order by time;
```

for the following table structure

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `function_logger` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `unit_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `part_id` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `channel` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `function` tinyint(11) NOT NULL,
  `time` datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

ALTER TABLE `function_logger`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `unit_id` (`unit_id`);
```

The table contains about 80 million records but takes around a minute to run. Once cached it is fine.

unit_id contains around 3000 different random numbers, part_id upto 10 and channel upto 3.

Is there anyway to speed this up?

Would partitioning help?

Comment: Add a covering index `alter table function_logger add index search_idx(unit_id,part_id,channel,time)`

Comment: What's the point in converting `time` from one timezone to the same timezone?

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty: That's not a covering index...

Comment: @eggyal, the system supports multiple timezones, and that seemed like an easy option.
However, now I look at it, there is no point adding that for users already in this timezone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming a uniform distribution of `unit_id`, then selecting a specific one (of 3000) amongst 80m records leaves you with over 25k records to examine.

Since you have no further indexing to assist, MySQL must currently retrieve and inspect every single one of those 25k records in order to determine whether they match the remaining filter criteria.

Adding a [*composite*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_index_(database)) index (i.e. one that is defined over multiple columns) would help you here—MySQL can thereby further reduce the records that it need examine.  However, with such low cardinality, `part_id` and `channel` may not help much.  It's not clear what sort of cardinality might exist from `time`, but that's probably a good starting point:

```
CREATE INDEX unit_time ON function_logger (unit_id, time)
```

You could add the other filter columns too (though beware that `time` should come last, since you're searching a range upon it)—however, the more columns in the index, the slower that writes to the table will become (and the larger that the index file and memory footprint will be).

The fastest read performance would be obtained from a [*covering*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_index#Covering_index) index:

```
CREATE INDEX covering ON function_logger (
  unit_id, part_id, channel, time, function
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much.

With the covering index it now selects the records virtually instantly.

Answer (score 0):

When trying/tesing different  indexes execute the explain and compare the results. USE INDEX will help you to test different indexes adding that hint in the select statement (remember not to use the qc).

```
set profiling = on;

select * from function_logger;
show profiles;
show profile for query N;
```